# Spring - Scan specific jar files

Tags: java, spring, annotations, classpath

Is it possible to tell spring to only scan (for annotations) those jars which are specified to it. I know we can specify the classpath, but it is slow because it needs to go into each jar in the web-inf/lib to look for classes that match that classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to tell spring to only scan (for annotations) those jars which are specified to it?

Well you can not scan jars but you can scan `packages` inside `jars` but those package should contain `Stereotyped annotated classes`.

> I know we can specify the classpath, but it is slow because it needs to go into each jar in the web-inf/lib to look for classes that match that classpath.

What you know is wrong. Spring does not scan classpath but packages under classpath for `Stereotyped annotated classes`.